# How to display Tapku in my view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tapku

I have an app that has an icon on the home screen that does a segue to my view controller.  I have a `UIViewController` with a view and a navigation bar.  I am trying to show the calendar, but it is not appearing.

My `UIViewController` is called `ViewCOntrollerCalendar` and in the `init` method I am doing the following:

```
calendar = [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];
calendar.delegate = self;
calendar.dataSource = self;
```

and then in my `viewDidLoad` I am doing this:

```
[self.view addSubview:calendar];
[calendar reload];
```

But the calendar never appears.  I have looked all over for an example, but I can not find anything that loads the calendar based off of a button.  I am fairly new to Xcode so I am sure I am missing something foolish.

I would like to have the calendar appear with the navigation bar at the top.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks